# Регулярные выражения для преобразование текста

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Есть большой текст. Задача в том чтобы заменить ВСЮ строку с определенным словом  через рег. выражения в Notepad++ на такую же добавив теги.

Вот часть текста.

> Характеристика работ. Бурение шпуров ручными и колонковыми перфораторами, электросверлами, пойнтами, ручными бурами.
>
> При бурении шпуров вручную - 3-й разряд;
>
> при бурении шпуров ручными и колонковыми перфораторами и электросверлами массой до 35 кг

А надо чтоб выглядело (добавлены теги):

> `<a>`Характеристика работ. Бурение шпуров ручными и колонковыми перфораторами, электросверлами, пойнтами, ручными бурами.`</a>`
>
> При бурении шпуров вручную - 3-й разряд;
>
> при бурении шпуров ручными и колонковыми перфораторами и электросверлами массой до 35 кг

И так в каждом абзаце этого большого текста, должны найти строку с `Характеристика работ` и изменить.

Не могу выделить всю строку, получается либо весь текст либо только Характеристика работы.

Comment: Сообщение содержит лишь текст задачи, в котором нет описания проблемы, либо вопрос чисто формален («как мне выполнить это задание»). Добавьте описание конкретной проблемы, поясните, что именно не получается, в чём вы видите проблему.

Comment: У вас есть ВК или Скайп я тут не могу пояснить всю суть задания, не поленитесь помогите разобраться

Comment: Александр, да нет уж, это вы не поленитесь. Ответьте на вопросы уточняющие, например. Через мессенджеры тут не работают — вопрос и ответы должны быть доступны для всех.

Comment: Неужели ни один человек не хочет помочь, просто поймите я не силен в рег. выражениях а точнее вообще в первый сталкиваюсь, у меня есть документ Ворд с полным заданием открыв который большинство из вас решат эту задачу за 5 минут, пожалуйста не упирайтесь давайте индивидуально решим этот вопрос, потом зальем сюда полноценный ответ, как вы видите я даже не могу правильно до вас донести суть задачи

Comment: @Александр не волнуйтесь так, сейчас разберемся. Для начала расскажите, а какую вы вообще задачу решаете таким образом? В документе Word теги XML не очень-то нужны. И работать с XML и тем более HTML лучше не регулярными выражениями, а специальными библиотеками-парсерами.

Comment: Нет это нужно сделать в Notepad++, просто задание у меня с иллюстрацией в Ворде, который я сюда не могу залить, я потому и прошу вас связаться со мной вк или в скайпе как удобно

Comment: @Александр регулярным выражениям несложно научиться за час-полтора. Например, здесь: https://regexone.com/

Comment: Я уже часов 12 сижу за этим и не могу выделить всю строку, Ник Если вы реально хотите помочь позвоните пожалуйста в скайп   
  sayabek1994

Comment: @Александр вам тут не биржа фриланса фо фри.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
(Характеристика работ.*).*$

<a>\1</a>
```

Comment: Не подходит, выделяется весь текст, в общем перед характеристикой поставить тег не тяжело, но добавить его в конце невозможно. Все что нужно это выделить ВСЮ строку со словом Характеристика работ, но чтоб я не делал два варианта, либо выделяется только характеристика работ либо весь огромный текст

Comment: обновлено......

Comment: Все равно выделяет весь текст я хз почему, но вы очень близки кажется, я тоже примерно это вводил но все по кругу хожу

Comment: А нет все спасибо дружище!!! Кажется получилось

Comment: @Александр, прими ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него.

Comment: А не перемудрили вы тут? `Характеристика работ.*` => `<a>$0</a>` - и всё.